# I want to download the coffee-rails 3.0.6 individually, without whole rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I want to download the coffee-rails 3.0.6 individually, without whole rails installation

Is there any way to download it separately?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is simple gem archive, then go to https://rubygems.org/gems/coffee-rails and just download this gem, then you can install it with just `gem install coffee-rails.gem` command.

But I'm not sure why you want to do it? Coffee-rails is just an adapter for coffee-script for Rails, it doesn't provide any functionality without Rails.